# Looping through a url list

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created a script that goes to a property auction site that monitors the price and alerts me of any of the changes. I originally made it to monitor 1 url at a time. I now need it to monitor more then 1 url and do the same exact process at the same time.

I've tried looping the urls in `browser.get` but that doesn't seem to work for me(idk if i wrote it wrong, probably did). But i need it to either, open a tun of new tabs and go to the urls, or another way for it to monitor everything.

Here is all my code

```
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import ssl
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

urls = ['https://www.hubzu.com/property/90089436968-730-Trillium-Ln-Lilburn-GA-30047',
'https://www.hubzu.com/property/90016097522-225-Marriott-Ave-Schenectady-NY-12304',
'https://www.hubzu.com/property/90016098285-17-Spring-Meadows-Dr-Ormond-Beach-FL-32174'
]

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# Start URL switch tryouts.

while True:
    for url in urls:
        browser.get((url))


       #This is the process i need all urls to do.
        time.sleep(2)
        address = soup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser').find('span', {'class':'h1'}).text
        propertyprice = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.current-bid')
        currentBidText = propertyprice.text
        try:                                
            WebDriverWait(browser, 90000).until_not(
                EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.current-bid'), currentBidText)
                )
        finally:
            print("+++ Send notifications.")
            account_sid = "***"
            auth_token = "***"
            client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

            PhoneNumber1 = "+***"
            PhoneNumber2 = "+***"
            print("+ Send notifications to: ", PhoneNumber1, " and ", PhoneNumber2)

            sendTo1 = "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"" + PhoneNumber1 + "\"}"
            print("+ sendTo1: ", sendTo1)
            sendTo2 = "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"" + PhoneNumber2 + "\"}"
            print("+ sendTo2: ", sendTo2)

            notify_service_sid = "***"
            notification = client.notify.services(notify_service_sid).notifications.create(
                    body='There has been a change at: '+address,
                    to_binding=[sendTo1, sendTo2]
                )

            print("+ Notification SID: ", notification.sid)

            print("+++ Exit.")
    continue
```

PS: Keep in mind, if auctions have expired there will be a error. Because it cannot find `span.current-bid`

Comment: Just for clarification, does it work for each URL individually if you're NOT trying to loop over multiple?

Comment: Yes. as long as url is in `browser.get`

Comment: It would normally look like `browser.get(('www.example.com'))`

Comment: Okay, and what's wrong with the looping code? What error are you getting, what is it NOT doing, etc?

Comment: There are no errors. Its just not looping. It goes to the first url, and does its job on that url. But it doesn't loop to the other 2.